# How to run Object Oriented PHP code in Apache tomcat 8

Tags: php

I am not be able to deploy PHP folder into Apache tomcat 8 . I had put my PHP Project folder to webapp in tomcat but still its not runnig.

Comment: Please put more detail about your folder structure and how you're trying to deploy it with Tomcat.

Comment: What is not running php or tomcat ? what kind of tutorial you followed ?

Comment: Does structural code run in Apache Tomcat 8?

Comment: I follwed these link: http://tojackwu.blogspot.com/2008/10/php-5-on-tomcat-6-installation.html

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/tomcat6.php